# Mermaid Technology

Tags: technology, civilization, merfolk

I'm tinkering around with an idea based on a mermaid civilization unbeknownst to humanity. The problem is, I'd rather write this with a better knowledge of what's scientifically possible, as opposed to pure fantasy.

My main question is how advanced could an underwater society be? Technology as we know it couldn't be practically implemented, so what sort of concepts could I play with?

I'm thinking I may just have to resort to them being more of native tribes. It's the only way I can think of them living without possible detection from humans.

Advice?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate - this is a good question, but see the first answer: many questions cover this topic.

Answer (score 6):

Too long to be a comment. A quick search of the word 'underwater' and 'aquatic' in the question search box yielded these results

- [Could underwater living organism create technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/could-underwater-living-organism-create-technology)
- [How could an underwater civilization develop fire?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31175/how-could-an-underwater-civilization-develop-fire)
- [How could an underwater civilization develop electricity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30927/how-could-an-underwater-civilization-develop-electricity)
- [How do underwater societies develop mining?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/44861/how-do-underwater-societies-develop-mining)
- [How would an aquatic civilisation forge tools?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/how-would-an-aquatic-civilisation-forge-tools?noredirect=1&lq=1)

as well as,

- [What would be the communication range of an underwater species?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/what-would-be-the-communication-range-of-an-underwater-species)
- [What could an aquatic civilization use to write on/with?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/59791/what-could-an-aquatic-civilization-use-to-write-on-with)
- [Low-tech Underwater Weaponry](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30561/low-tech-underwater-weaponry)
- [What would make good clothing for an underwater species?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/what-would-make-good-clothing-for-an-underwater-species)
- [What types of musical instruments would develop underwater?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20438/what-types-of-musical-instruments-would-develop-underwater)
- [How could there be underwater thriving city in the medieval age?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39676/how-could-there-be-underwater-thriving-city-in-the-medieval-age?rq=1)

Have a look at those, and if you still have some questions...maybe you can narrow it down a bit.

FYI, maybe we have noticed them...we just [don't know it](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/bloop-mystery-not-solved-sort-of) or [won't accept it.](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2333515/Mermaid-hoax-How-mockumentary-gave-Animal-Planet-biggest-audience-EVER.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming water basically acts in your world as it does in ours, then they're going to have real trouble confining heat (because of water's great heat capacity and conductivity); ditto creating/confining any soluble chemicals.  They might make use of ocean currents for power, assuming usable building materials.  What materials could they/would they use?  Perhaps they can't -- until they start recycling materials from sunken ships.

On the other hand, any mermaid/man who could control local heating (and live to tell the tale) would have a fearsome power: cook or steam-explode one's enemies.